# 3 dynamic divs inside a parent div with fixed size

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble here, I am trying to create three divs with varying width inside  a parent div of fixed width. Is there anyway to have the divs adjust themselves based on how much space is in there? basically all three divs will have varying size and needs to fill the parent div. The divs also need to be on the same line. Height is not an issue.

Something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes...it is...but what have you tried?

Comment: I tried using float: left, but that didn't work, they need to be on the same plane. Also width: 100% didn't seem to work.

Comment: with float you need to set first 2 elements floatting and the last in the flow. 3 methods (float,table,flex) for similar behavior http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwRZqG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox to the rescue!

For this example, I used `justify-content: space-between`, but there are a lot of different options.

[Wonderful overview of flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>One</div>
  <div class="grow">Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it, additonally, is it possible to make the middle div expand to fill the remaining space if there is any?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Absolutely. Add `flex-grow: 1` to the middle div.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest would probably be:

```
#parent {
    display: table-row;
}
#parent div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This will cause the elements to behave like an HTML table. (you could also just use a table to make things easier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use some CSS rules to achieve the behavior you are describing. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfmj4ca8/1/

- `max-width: 33%;` ensures that the 3 divs will at most take up 99% width
- `display: inline-block;` makes the divs appear inline.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me, the parent div has a fixed width. The divs inside has varying width.

Answer (score 0):

How about doung it like this.

```css
div#parent{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}
div#parent > div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 32%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```